# How to keep all the original data entered present in result even though SQL Server returns no result for them?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm running a simple query of extracting all the information from the table ftfuk.ProductDimension_UK using a list of ProductBarcode as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM ftfuk.ProductDimension_UK
WHERE ProductBarcode IN (
        '0000000026222'
        ,'25050097'
        ,'25050103'
        ,'111122'
        ,'3333444'
        )
```

The result looks like:

```
ProductBarcode  ProductStatus
-----------------------------
0000000026222   Active
```

And ultimately I want my result to look like:

```
ProductBarcode  ProductStatus
-----------------------------
0000000026222   Active
25050097         
25050103
111122
3333444
```

I am using SQL server 2014. Any way of getting this worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `values` construct & do `left join` :

```
select t.ProductBarcode, coalesce(uk.ProductStatus, '') as ProductStatus
from ( values ('0000000026222'), . . , ('3333444') 
     ) t(ProductBarcode) left join
     ftfuk.ProductDimension_UK uk
     on uk.ProductBarcode = t.ProductBarcode;
```

Comment: what is table t?

Comment: @Evelii. . . `t` is user defined alias. By, you can use it with `SELECT` statement.

Comment: it is a [table value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)